# call p:dialog from another p:dialog : datas are empty

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a big problem with my dialogs, the datas from the datatable are empty when I call a dialog from another dialog

Explaination :

-> I have a datatable with a "details" button which open a dialog1 : No problem

-> I have a "create" button in this dialog1 which open a dialog2 : No problem 
(dialog1 and datatable are surrounded by h:form id="form")

-> In the dialog2 I CAN'T see the datas from the datatable : Big problem.
(dialog2 is surrounded by h:form id="form7")

=> My question is : How to receive datas from datatable in the dialog2 that calls dialog1, maybe it's impossible with Primefaces?

What do you think?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. My first thoughts are that reading [tour] (again?), reading [ask] and [mcve] are the things to do. They help you improve your question, so they are the best things to do. Including posting version info.

Comment: My second thought is that _"maybe it's impossible with Primefaces?"_ is not true... 100% certain.

Comment: I cannot post code in stackoverflow, I use the "{}" button but half of my code is displayed, never seen that !!

Comment: Then you do something wrong. If you make a [mcve] and post that and not all is visible, please do post it and ask others to check it....

Comment: `half of my code is displayed` - maybe you missed the fact that there was a scroll bar that can be used to see the other half? OffTopic: @Kukeltje hope all is ok with you, just saw the news.